# Read a string from a file including white space and search a file for a given string in C

Tags: c, string

I am trying to search a string in a text file,when the text file is like what given below :

```
"Naveen; Okies
PSG; Diploma
SREC; BECSE"
```

When output console ask for input string and when i type naveen it will result in printing Okies, when i typed PSG it will print Diploma. This works fine as I am using the below code :

```
fscanf(fp, "%[^;];%s\n", temp, Mean);
```

However below text file is not working,

```
"Naveen; Okies Is it working
PSG; Diploma Is it working
SREC; BECSE Is it working"
```

My code still gives me Okies as output for Naveen, where i need "Okies Is it working" as output.

So i changed my code to `fscanf(fp, "%[^;];%[^\n]s", temp, Mean);` where i am getting 'Okies Is it working' as output. But for searching string it's not searching next line. When i search PSG, I dont get any ouput.

Kindly help me to understand my issue.

Comment: If I were you I would read the whole line with e.g. [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets), then use [`strtok`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) to split at the separator character.

Answer (score 3):

#### Side-bar

Note that you should check the return value from `fscanf()`.

You say you tried:

```
fscanf(fp, "%[^;];%[^\n]s", temp, Mean);
```

This is probably a confused format.  The `s` at the end is looking for a literal `s` in the input, but it will never be found and you'll have no way of knowing that it is not found.  The `%[^\n]` scan set conversion specification looks for a sequence of 'non-newlines'.  It will only stop when the next character is a newline, or EOF.  The `s` therefore is a literal `s` that will never be matched.  But the return values from `fscanf()` is the number of successful conversions, which would probably be 2.  You have no way of spotting whether that `s` was read. It should be removed from the format string.

---

#### Main answer

To address your main question, the `%s` format stops at the first blank.  If you want to process the whole line, don't use `%s`.  Use either POSIX [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) or standard C [`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html) to read the line, and then analyze it.

You can analyze it with [`strtok()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtok.html).  I wouldn't do that in any library code because any library function that calls `strtok()` cannot be used from code that might also be using `strtok()`, nor can it call any function where that function, or one of the functions it calls directly or indirectly, uses `strtok()`.  The `strtok()` function is poisonous — you can only use it in one function at a time.  These comments do not apply to 
[`strtok_r()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtok_r.html) or the analogous Microsoft-provided variant [`strtok_s()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ftsafwz3.aspx) — which is similar to but different from the `strtok_s()` defined in optional Annex K of C11.  The variants with a suffix are reentrant and do not poison the system like `strtok()` does.

I'd probably use [`strchr()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strchr.html) in this context; you could also look at
[`strstr()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strstr.html),
[`strpbrk()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strpbrk.html),
[`strspn()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strspn.html),
[`strcpsn()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strcpsn.html).  All of these are standard C functions, and have been since C89/C90.

Answer (score 0):

I think Jonathan has explained it pretty well, however, I am adding a sample to show how to deal with your example for learning purposes. Bear in mind you might wanna change some functions as I used the deprecated (insecure) ones, probably this could be an exercise for you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *fp = NULL;
    char szBuffer[1024] = { '\0' };
    char szChoice[256] = { '\0' };
    char szResult[256] = { '\0' };

    if ((fp = fopen("test.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
        printf("Error opening file\n");

        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("Enter your choice: ");
    scanf("%s", &szChoice);

    while (fgets(szBuffer, sizeof(szBuffer), fp) != NULL) {
        if (!strncmp(szBuffer, szChoice, strlen(szChoice))) {
            char *pch = szBuffer;

            pch += (strlen(szChoice) + 1);

            printf("Result: %s", pch);
        }
    }

    getchar();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Both :-) .. I will try this ... I cannot upvote as i have not reached 15 pnts